# Unexpected pipe 'EscapeHtmlPipe in escape-html.pipe.ts Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, build, angular7, angular-pipe

Running `ng build --prod` gives me the following error.

ERROR in : Unexpected pipe 'EscapeHtmlPipe in escape-html.pipe.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Works fine on `ng serve`. Problem with `ng build --prod` only

The code in file is given below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import{ EscapeHtmlPipe } from '../../Shared/pipes/escape-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [EscapeHtmlPipe],
  exports: [EscapeHtmlPipe]
})
export class EscapeHtmlModule { }
```

The code file for pipe is given below

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'escapeHtml'
})
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }

}
```

in AppModule I have  done this

```
import { EscapeHtmlModule } from './Module/escape-html/escape-html.module';
```

the NgModule part is given below

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // EscapeHtmlPipe,
    NavMenuComponent,
    OpportunityComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    TinymceComponent,
    SummaryComponent,
    OpportunityListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DragDropModule,
    ScrollDispatchModule,
    EditorModule,
    // EscapeHtmlPipe,

    DragulaModule.forRoot(), 
    ContextMenuModule.forRoot(), EscapeHtmlModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RFPDocumentService,
    ColorChangeService,
    CategoryService,
    InsertCategoryAttributeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[TinymceComponent,OpportunityListComponent]
})
```

But the problem was even exist before I added EscapeHtmlModule in the middle ware as earlier I was adding the pipe directly in AppModule and that was generating the error.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: please share @NgModule part of AppModule

Comment: I updated the question you can see NgModule part of it .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message: `ERROR in : Unexpected pipe 'EscapeHtmlPipe in escape-html.pipe.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation` says that you are importing the `EscapeHtmlPipe` directly into the `AppModule`. You need to be importing the `EscapeHtmlModule` into your `AppModule` not the `EscapeHtmlPipe`.

Here is a basic example of the flow when creating shared Modules with shared `Pipes` (or `Components` and `Directives`):

1. Create a new `NgModule` (which you have called EscapeHtmlModule)
2. Create the `Pipe` and add it to the EscapeHtmlModule's `declarations` and `exports` arrays
3. Add whichever other Modules that your pipe needs to work to the `imports` array
4. Go to your `AppModule` and import the `EscapeHtmlModule` (add it to the `imports` array)